# Append items from list A to list B, if they are not already in list B

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So say I have the following lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [5,2,3]
c = [5,4,2]
```

I would like to append the unique items from each list as they are looped over into a new array to end up with:

```
unique_list = [1,2,3,5,4]
```

I still don't full comprehend list comprehension for more advanced cases, however I'm thinking the following clearly incorrect code would convey my intentions:

```
def append_unique(new_list):
    unique_list.append(item) for item in new_list if item not in unique_list
unique_list = []    

append_unique([1,2,3])
append_unique([5,2,3])
append_unique([5,4,2])
```

Is this even possible with a one-liner, or should I concede and go for a nested solution?

*UPDATE*

Sorry I don't think I've conveyed this particularly well, I need to add each additional list's unique items as part of a loop, hence why each needs to individually pass through `append_unique()`

I attempted to modify `append_unique()` to use `set()` as per the following:

```
def append_unique(new_list):
    unique_list = list(set(unique_list + new_list))
unique_list = []    

append_unique([1,2,3])
append_unique([5,2,3])
append_unique([5,4,2])
```

The problem here of course is that I get the error, which I don't fully understand how to get around:

```
local variable 'unique_list' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Does `unique_list` need to be ordered?

Comment: not at all, however it does need to be updated in a loop rather than `a+b+c`. Updated OP to clarify this.

Comment: You might be interested in the second part of my solution

Comment: Yeah that's the way I've been falling back to, the main purpose of this question was to try and use list comprehension, which it seems is not possible, however the `set()` idea also looked promising as a one-liner. As it stands though, I'm using a solution very similar to your second part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order does not matter, you can use sets:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [5,2,3]
>>> c = [5,4,2]
>>> set(a+b+c)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

If it does, then you can use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> res = []
>>> for ele, _ in groupby(a+b+c):
...     if ele not in res:
...             res.append(ele)
...
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Order does not matter, however as I've stated in the updated OP, appending via loop does matter. As per your second solution however, that's what I'm using currently until I find the "better" answer I'm hoping to find :). I don't understand why you are using `seen` at all, and what benefit this provides over simply `if ele not in res:` ?

Comment: @DanH Huh, why aren't I indeed. I think I'm getting mixed up with something else. Lol, changing

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using sets, the following code might work for you:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [5,2,3]
>>> c = [5,4,2]

>>> my_set = set(a) | set(b) | set(c)

>>> my_set
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> unique_list = list(my_set)
>>> unique_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```